# Setup of the Eclipse debugger in MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to debug a project from within the Eclipse IDE. After setting up the project paths I can properly build and run. However when I try to debug I get into this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot open file for reading: /Users/manfredo/Documents/Eclipse_workspace/Formind/formind-model/src/'../../formind_proj/FrenchGuiana_Paracou_Lianas/lowlandTropicalForest_9pft/formind_parameters/paracouForest_controlPlots_9pft.par' . File: ./for_iommparset.h  Line: 1356
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: ERROR: Cannot open file for reading: /Users/manfredo/Documents/Eclipse_workspace/Formind/formind-model/src/'../../formind_proj/FrenchGuiana_Paracou_Lianas/lowlandTropicalForest_9pft/formind_parameters/paracouForest_controlPlots_9pft.par' . File: ./for_iommparset.h  Line: 1356
```

From the terminal I can run my executable in GDB normally:

```
[src]$ gdb ./formind
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./formind...done.
(gdb) r ../../formind_proj/FrenchGuiana_Paracou_Lianas/lowlandTropicalForest_9pft/formind_parameters/paracouForest_controlPlots_9pft.par
Starting program: /Users/manfredo/Documents/Eclipse_workspace/Formind/formind-model/src/formind ../../formind_proj/FrenchGuiana_Paracou_Lianas/lowlandTropicalForest_9pft/formind_parameters/paracouForest_controlPlots_9pft.par
[New Thread 0x1403 of process 13482]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)
Initialize lookup vectors
=================== Start Simulation=======================

...
=============== Simulation Successful =====================
Runtime: 0.809137 seconds
[Inferior 1 (process 13482) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Any idea about the solution?
I am running Eclipse Photon on a MacOS 10.12.6

Answer (score 0):

You are probably debugging the binary with wrong arguments in Eclipse.

Compare the path to a file in Eclipse:

```
/Users/manfredo/Documents/Eclipse_workspace/Formind/formind-model/src/'../../formind_proj/FrenchGuiana_Paracou_Lianas/lowlandTropicalForest_9pft/formind_parameters/paracouForest_controlPlots_9pft.par'
```

and the path to a file in standalone gdb:

```
../../formind_proj/FrenchGuiana_Paracou_Lianas/lowlandTropicalForest_9pft/formind_parameters/paracouForest_controlPlots_9pft.par
```

I guess the path to a file should be the same as the one for standalone gdb.

Comment: When I run the application in the debugger I do: `gdb ./formind` and then `r paracouForest_controlPlots_9pft.par` because the application needs to be run with that argument. Now if I remove that argument from the argument list in the debugger configuration of Eclipse my application starts but terminates immediately because it does not have the input parameters. How do I add them if not in the argument section of the debugger options?

Comment: A partial solution can be found [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1087092/). Basically it's setting the arguments in the .gdbinit. However because the argument list is the same for both debug and run, this means that when I run the application I don't have the argument appended and hence I get a failure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to set up debugger arguments in Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, anyway from the discussion in the previous link it looks like am unresolved bug. I guess the only option is waiting for a fix.